# Angular newbie questions

Tags: angular, npm, continuous-integration, dependencies, gitlab

dear angular community,

i recently started with an angular projekt for my school. i have never used angular before and need some help. maybe you guys can give me a little kickstart.

first of all i created a new projekt installed bootstrap, chartjs and material design and typed ng serve
the first message i get is

> Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm update`

i tried to update but it doesn't work. why ist there already something which is outdated?

this is my package.json:

```html
{
  "name": "tqr-analytics",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.5.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.1.5",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.3.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.21",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.21",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~13.1.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.5.4",
    "tslint": "~5.20.1",
    "typescript": "~3.5.0"
  }
}
```

then tried to figure out how i can implement some tests with karma and they worked fine locally on my workstation. of course i need to make a pipeline for ci/cd with gitlab and heroku cause i heard of it and wanted to try this out. but the test fails on gitlab.

[image]

i had the same error locally and could fix it with an npm install of the angular dev package but i am not able to figure out how i can do this on gitlab.

to goal of this whole setup is to have a good base so that i can develop a dashboard with angular and show the principle of ci/cd.

my gitlab-ci.yml looks like this:

[image]

i am also not sure if the way i setup this gitlab-ci-yml is correct, if you have any suggestions please let me know.

thanks for reading this.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16560#issuecomment-571755869

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could solve the problem. i updated my gitlab-ci.yml and added npm ci to the srcipt part.

```
test:
  stage: test
  image: trion/ng-cli-karma:${CLI_VERSION}
  allow_failure: false
  script:
    - npm ci
    - ng test --progress false --watch false
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 day
    paths:
      - dist/
  tags:
  - docker
```

not quite sure if this is the right way but it works.